# How to make the code print original value then print new value?

Tags: octave

I have a homework to write a Matlab program, but the issue I am facing is the program is printing the updated value. I need to print the old value then print the new value.

I tried using vectors and loop to do it but I am kinda lost with it.

```
for i=2:10000   %Starting from 2 since Octave Index starts from 1.

xmid=(xu+xl)/2;   %Finding the middle Value
if f(xl)*f(xmid)>0  %Test first condition for bisection.
    xl=xmid;
else
    xu=xmid;
    end

fprintf('%2i \t %f \t %f \t %f \n', i-1, xl, xu, xmid);   

xnew(1)=0;
xnew(i)=xmid;
if abs((xnew(i)-xnew(i-1))/xnew(i))<tol,break,end  %Test the error value.
    end
```

In above code, when `f(xl)*f(xmid)>0`, the program should print old `xl` value then update it to `xmid` and same also for `xu` and `xmid`.

Comment: This does not look like C

Comment: Please use only relevant tags, and look at the tag excerpts to learn when to use them. The code is Octave, not C. It might be MATLAB, but my guess is you use Octave. Please correct me if I’m wrong. I suggest you think of other tags relevant to the question and [edit] them in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Get the old values of the bounds first ***before evaluating the condition***
- Then display them
- Initialize `xnew` before the for loop, like xnew = zeros(1, 10000);

Read through the comments

```
% Initialization for illustration
f = @(x)2*x-1;
xu = 10;
xl = 5;
tol = 0.5;
xnew = zeros(1, 10);

fprintf('\t  xlold \t  xlnew\t\t  xuold \t  xunew \t midlle\n\n');  
for i=2:10  %Starting from 2 since Octave Index starts from 1.

    xmid=(xu+xl)/2;   %Finding the middle Value
    % get the old bounds first 
    xlold = xl;
    xuold = xu;
    if f(xl)*f(xmid)>0  %Test first condition for bisection.
        xl=xmid;
    else
        xu=xmid;
    end

    % add xold and xulod here
    fprintf('%2i \t %f \t %f \t %f \t %f \t %f \n', i-1, xlold,xl, xuold,xu, xmid);   

    xnew(1)= 0;
    xnew(i)= xmid;
    if abs((xnew(i)-xnew(i-1))/xnew(i))<tol %Test the error value.
       break;
    end  
end
```

**Result**

```
      xlold       xlnew       xuold       xunew      midlle

 1   5.000000    7.500000    10.000000   10.000000   7.500000 
 2   7.500000    8.750000    10.000000   10.000000   8.750000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
    oldxl = xl;
    oldxu = xu;
    // your code that updates xl and xu
    printf("oldxl: %f; oldxu: %f\n", oldxl, oldxu);
```

Comment: I just tried playing with it by adding (i-1) but still didnt work!